# SugarmCRM: Upload document files to S3 bucket instead of cache/upload in sugar 6.2

Tags: sugarcrm

I am on SugarCRM 6.2 CE.
My requirement is to push the document to S3 bucket instead of sugar's local directory. Like when user uploads a document, it should go to s3 bucket. For this I want to know which file I need to change. Any suggestion ?

Comment: This question is interesting. I only know a place in config.php where the upload gets defined. 'upload_dir' => 'upload/',  Maybe this variable name helps you search the right place in the code

Comment: I found include/SugarFields/Fields/File/SugarFieldFile.php. We can customise this file